# github: where is the "download or clone" button?

Tags: github, download, git-clone

github: where is the "download or clone" button? There used to be a button:

```
Download or Clone
```

The button is missing on github.com project page.

How to download code from master or a tag? What is HTTPS URL for git clone?

### UPDATE

The button is gone when browser is zoomed at 179%. Is it a bug of responsive design?

Comment: It's a design choice. The code button disappears if `@media (min-width: 768px)` is not true. The pixel size is defined in your case, by the zoom level

Comment: A *really annoying* design choice when using a tiling window manager.... In case anyone else coming across this is annoyed enough to install a userstyle, I wrote one: https://userstyles.world/style/6521/github-always-show-clone

Comment: @eastwater fancy posting a better answer than either of the current ones? If not, I am happy to oblige.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for this!  I was having the same issue using SwayWM with at least 2 windows side-by-side... GitHub's responsive design CSS always hides the `<> Code` button which is quite an annoying productivity killer.  Definitely the wrong UI/UX assumption was made about screen size being an indicator for being on a device where a Clone URL wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sunnyday
It is under the code button. Please check. Try exploring before asking here. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The button is gone when my browser is zoomed at 179%. :))

Comment: This also happens on mobile, android , iphone and ipad split screen. In their infinite wisdom GitHub by Microsoft decided we shouldn't code on phones.

Answer (score 6):

Click the <>Code button top left, it takes you to a different view from where you can download

Answer (score 0):

An Android device is lacking of the CODE button in the browser "Chrome" and "Firefox", but you can try an other browser "duckduckgo.com" or "idm downloader".

For me, the button was then visible.

You have to ensure that the screen resolution **is at least 768px**, which was earlier of an 17 inch display.

Hope it will help.